# Delphi 10.4 Android signing scheme for APK

Tags: android, delphi, deployment, apk, signing

What signing scheme is used for Delphi 10.4 Android?

I require v2 scheme for android APK

here is a link to the V2 signing scheme for android
https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v2

It does not look like I have control of this in delphi

The error received when installing on Android:
Signature not found - No APK Signing Block before ZIP Central Directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Delphi 10.4.2 doesn't support Version 2 signing for APK, because this feature came out with Android SDK 30 (after Delphi 10.4.2 release). Also, Delphi doesn't provide the ability to edit or manage the scripts used to create the APKs. So you will have to wait for EMBT to upgrade them with each new Delphi release.

As a workaround, you have to re-sign your APKs manually:
Open the command prompt, and set the active directory to your installed Android SDK's Build tools, something like this :
`C:\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk\build-tools\29.0.3`

Verify the signature of your APK with this command :
`apksigner.bat verify --verbose PathOfAPK`.
This will output this result :

```
  Verifies
  Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
  Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): false
  Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
  Number of signers: 1
```

Now, resign your APK with this command (change to your appropriate keystore data) :
`apksigner.bat sign --ks PathToKeystore --ks-pass pass:KeystorePassword --ks-key-alias AliasName --key-pass pass:AliasPassword PathOfApk`

Finally, re-verify the signature of your APK with the same previous command :
`apksigner.bat verify --verbose PathOfAPK`. It will output this result :

```
  Verifies
  Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
  Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
  Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
  Number of signers: 1
```

It is possible to put the resigning command in Delphi PostBuild events.

And for bundles, you have to rely on Google signing.

For more informations about using the ApkSigner command line, check this link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner